# Local DNS Server on WSL

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have one Windows machine with WSL and nginx server at WSL running on it. Server works perfectly on local network, and other devices can see the website using Ip address of network interface of the windows machine. Other devices are primarily android smartphones. My question is: is that possible, and if yes, then how exactly, to set up simple local DNS server running on WSL? I would not like to edit hosts file on client devices (this is cumbersome, and I may not have access to all of these devices, and address can change), and I do not want to set up custom firmware on home router (this option may be as risky as not possible at all). I could set up dual boot, but I really don't like that idea. I have a faint hope on that idea, because my http server is working somehow. I heard about bind9, but as far as I am concerned, configuration is even more complicated here. So basically, questions are:

Is that possible to run that configuration?
If no, why exactly? And what are alternatives?
If yes, then how exactly?
I have tried to set up dnsmasq on WSL, but it works only on the host machine. I have tried to do that with default NAT networking mode of WSL with port proxy interface listening on ports 80 and 53, and with mirrored networking mode as well. Ports 80 TCP and 53 TCP/UDP are opened in Windows Firewall. I want to use local DNS server on WSL. I want to be able to use some address (say, local.site) for my website, not only at my host machine, but on other devices on my local network as well. All other addresses should be redirected either to some DNS service (say, 8.8.8.8), or to my home router, which in turn redirect that request to my ISP, so Network can work as usual except my specific address (and some other, possibly). My /etc/hosts file contain IP address of my host machine network interface with automatic generation disabled in /etc/wsl.conf. File /etc/resolv.conf is generated automatically. If my idea is feasible, I would like to know details of configuration with details about IP addresses, their location, and additional configuration details, such as WSL networking mode and firewall configuration. If it is not, I would like to know the reason and possible alternatives.

Comment: If BIND is to bulky for you (imho, it really isn't) there there shouldn't be any reason that dnsmasq wouldn't work.  But, and just a thought, Windows has a DNS server available as well and is quite easy to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as you can get packets for port 53 (TCP *and* UDP) delivered to the service.

There are very few differences between setting up an HTTP server and setting up a DNS server as far as networking requirements go. You need to have UDP available (not just TCP) and you cannot choose the port number (it's always 53), but other than that, everything is the same; a specific VM networking mode is not required.

Don't forget that your router still needs to be configured to *advertise* the new DNS server's address through DHCP (or all clients need to be manually configured to use it).

For software, I would actually start with BIND9 – it is not any more complex to configure than Nginx, and it supports acting both as an authoritative server (i.e. hosting your local domain) and as a resolver (i.e. looking up queries for external domains). It can do the latter either by forwarding to another DNS server, or entirely standalone.

Other popular options are Unbound (mainly a resolver, but recently gained the ability to host full zones), Dnsmasq (very common for small LANs and actually used by several models of home routers), and Microsoft DNS Server (comes with all Windows Server editions).

(Beware that some DNS servers are authoritative-*only* and would need to be paired with a separate resolver; e.g. if you were to use Knot or PowerDNS for hosting the domain, you would still need BIND/Unbound/Dnsmasq as a "frontend" that'd forward requests either to Knot or to 8.8.8.8. It's all a lot like web servers – some can host websites *and* be a reverse proxy, some can't proxy, some are exclusively just for proxying.)

Answer (score 0):

I started to check things out. Port 53 on UDP was mentioned on previous answer. Of course, as I mentioned in my question, this port is open in the Windows Firewall. But there is a catch, that I got only recently.

In order to redirect requests from my host machine to WSL, I use port proxy interface, technique recommended in Microsoft post, which listen requests to my host machine and redirect them to my WSL.

But as I discovered just now, this interface is available only on TCP. Thus, even if requests can reach to my host, and even if they can pass through firewall, they are not directed to my WSL.

Windows have no idea of what to do with them, so they are just left without response. I will try to use mirrored networking mode, maybe that would help.

Comment: Mirrored networking mode messes everything up. Distinction between host machine and WSL blurs (I guess, that had been done purposely), so it is pretty hard to direct requests to WSL manually. What had worked is [Simple UDP proxy/pipe](https://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm). It implements UDP port forwarding on Windows and works perfectly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can create _actual_ portforwarding rules in Hyper-V's NAT using PowerShell commands, although I haven't tried to do that so far. Appears to be [Add-NetNatStaticMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netnat/add-netnatstaticmapping?view=windowsserver2022-ps).

Comment: Yes, I also stumbled upon this option. It is native and probably works better. Simple UDP proxy/pipe works, but it is sort of a bottleneck. Connection is rather slow, and time outs are often. Another good option which I found recently is [DNS Mara](https://maradns.samiam.org/), which is also simple to set up, lightweight, and available for Windows.